# Linq2Sql opening the wrong database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am opening a LINQ 2 SQL connection to retrieve settings from a database. Our test environment has several databases that we use for testing, and one of the people using my application was using a different one than I use. The problem is, the data was still being taken from the database I was testing with, rather than the one she was using.

To simplyfy:
* I programmed using DataBaseTestOne
* A tester changed the connection text to used DataBaseTestTwo
* The data was loaded from DataBaseTestOne

The code I am using is as follows:

```
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (DbCommunicationDataContext context = new DbCommunicationDataContext())
        {
            var result = context.gprefs.FirstOrDefault();
            if (result != null)
            {
                Host = result.cpopserver;
                Port = Convert.ToInt32(result.npopport);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.LogEvent("There was an error loading settings:\n" + e);
    }
```

The gprefs table has only one line, that stores system preferences. I have stopped on the first line of this in debug mode and confirmed that connection is null and context does not exist at the beginning of the method. I have also confirmed that the connectionString points to the correct database (DataBaseTestTwo).

As a test, I tried replacing the connectionString with an empty string, and it still connected to DataBaseTestOne.

When I created the DataContext, I pulled tables from DataBaseTestOne, but have trouble believing that this means that I can only ever access that one database.

I am hoping that there is some simple issue that I am overlooking, but I can't seem to find it.

**Additional Information**

In the class that handles the database work, I found a setting under Properties -> Settings named DataBaseTestOne, with a connection text for that database. I tried deleting this, and got an error in the DbCommunication.designer.cs file on the below line:

```
public DbCommunicationDataContext() : 
        base(global::Utilities.Properties.Settings.Default.DataBaseTestOneConnectionString, mappingSource)
{
    OnCreated();
}
```

Is this reference there because that is where I took the initial tables from, or did I somehow hard-code this database in when I created the context? I'm betting that I can change the property to point to the database being used, but I don't remember having to do that in the past when I used Linq To Sql, plus this would leave a potential password in clear text.

Comment: Open the context designer file and right click -> view code. In the new partial class file add an overload to the OnCreated method. Use this to load the correct connection string from the config and set it to the connections connection string property. `partial void OnCreated(){Connection.ConnectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConn"].ConnectionString;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I never associated the connection with the data context. I modified my code as shown below, and things started working.

```
        //using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (DbCommunicationDataContext context = new DbCommunicationDataContext(connectionString))
        {
            var result = context.gprefs.FirstOrDefault();
            if (result != null)
            {
                wcf = result.cportlserver;
                resend = result.ndatsentaft.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

May be stupid, and I'd put this in as a comment if I could, but - check where the  database connection is defined? It's obviously pulling the connection from *somewhere*. A config file would be the obvious place to check.

EDIT: Sometimes, config settings are read only once, at the very start. You may need to restart the application in order for the change to take effect. I had to do stuff like this before and usually an IIS Reset would deal with it, everything would be re-initialized.

Comment: I had the same thought, and although the connection is opened a couple times to pull settings for various plugins, it is always closed, and the SqlConnection is always defined at the method level. I did check to see if the DataBaseTestOne name showed up anywhere in the code, and found it in the DbCommunication.dbml and DbCommunication.designer.cs, along with a couple other designers, and am looking into whether a connection might be derived from these somewhere.

Comment: also check whether the old connection is cached as per my edit.

Comment: I have stopped and started the program several times. Plus, It has been installed on different computers starting out with different connection texts, but still come back to the same database.

Comment: well, guess the only thing for it is a good old fashioned grep session on all the files for the connection definition.